# I need to modify this function to display specified age and more

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Modify the `displayAddress` function to display the street, city, and state of the location property of the user. Display it in the DIV with a CSS class of details. Use the street, city, state format

this is the little i can do as a bigginner programmer, i need help

```
   THE HTML

    <div class="details mdc-elevation--z3" >

        </div>
<div class="messages">
    </div>

THE JS



  const displayAddress = ({location = 'location'}) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.details').textContent = ('Location.(street, 
  city, state));

  };
```

Comment: Can you post the html part?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We are not here to just fix your stuff for you (especially not when it seems to be homework), without you making a reasonable effort first. _Show_ us what you tried, and _explain_ what problems you are having.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions - click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: Add the HTML and be clear on what you are expecting and what is your current result

Answer (score 0):

You didnt put space in your string
Do this
document.querySelector('.details').textContent = dob.age + ' years old';

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please put discussion and questions in comments section below answer/ question!